# How to convert a Markdown table from horizontal display to vertical in Python?

Tags: python, markdown

My code is this:

```
from tomark import Tomark
dict = [{ "key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"}]

markdown = Tomark.table(dict)
print(markdown)
```

The result is this:

| PR | Status | Date | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 292 | open | None | Adds new wiz bang feature |
| 286 | v1.0 | None | Updates UI to be more awesome |

Does anyone have an idea of how to make the key-value pair each one in a row?

How to modify the source class to achieve that?

Comment: Checked the Tomark source, it is only for tables with headers at the top and data rows. Best way would be to write your own function similar to it.
https://github.com/codazoda/tomark/blob/master/tomark/tomark.py

Comment: Yes I have been trying to do that, but since I am pretty new to this, I haven't managed to modify the function accordingly. But thank you for the answer

Comment: What output are you looking for? A table where the first column is the keys and the second is the values?

Comment: Yes that kind of output

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a single dictionary `my_dict`.
Then *Tomark* will output this as a single row (values) plus header (keys):

```
| key_a | key_b | key_c |
|-----|-----|-----|
| value_a | value_b | value_c |
```

#### Transpose the table

Now you want to transpose the table:

- Each column (dict item) should move to a separate row with 2 columns (key, value).
- The 2 columns need some new names given.

For your input data this means you have to iterate through the dictionary's items and transpose each item to a new dict with 2 entries, one for each column. And you have to name the *newly created columns*, e.g. `{"key": k, "value": v}`. This new dict is added as line to a list.

```py
from tomark import Tomark

my_dict = { "key_a":"value_a", "key_b":"value_b", "key_c":"value_c"}

transposed_list = []
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    transposed_list.append({"key": k, "value": v})

# print(transposed_list)
# [{'value': 'value_a', 'key': 'key_a'}, {'value': 'value_c', 'key': 'key_c'}, {'value': 'value_b', 'key': 'key_b'}]

markdown = Tomark.table(transposed_list)
print(markdown)
```

Prints:

```
| key | value |
|-----|-----|
| key_a | value_a |
| key_b | value_b |
| key_c | value_c |
```